# Making a monthly Report of a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, reports, power-automate

I am utilizing Power Automate to create a Flow that references data in SharePoint Online.  I have a SharePoint list and I want to send Monthly reports of items created in that list per month and which department has created how many reports (This data will be taken from one of the field in the list).

So far, I have been able to create the Recurrence Trigger and two variables `firstDayOfMonth` and `lastDayOfMonth` and I'm able to do the Get Items action as well but can't figure out where to go from here.  Below are the screenshots of the Flow that I have created so far.

[image][image][image]

I want the workflow to send the report to the manager and I have also created a document library in SharePoint where I want the reports to be saved monthly.

Comment: We are missing some of the steps in your Flow -- can you screen capture your Trigger and what comes after?

Comment: HI @Willman. I have updated the post and added another picture which is of the full workflow. Have a look please.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your recurrence trigger.  It appears that your Flow will create a separate report and email for every item in the Change Request list -- is that your intent?  What output are you getting now?

Comment: It keeps going on the Apply to each and then it fails in the end. Can't figure out what to do. I want to get the reports from the list for example No. of reports submitted in the last month etc.

Comment: Well, I will need to you to share the error message you are getting, and expand out the Advanced Settings on your Get Items action, as I can't see what criteria you are using.  The Create File and Send Email actions will definitely need to be moved to After the Loop instead of inside it, but will need to create a variable to hold your report information that will be composed in the loop.

Comment: It runs for like 3 hours and then gives this error at the end. Duration
02:57:22
Status
Failed
Error:
Action 'Create_file' failed
Error Details:
BadGateway

Comment: Are you trying to save the file to an on-prem SharePoint server?  If your target site is at https://[yourtenant].sharepoint.com, it shouldn't be possible to get a BadGateway error.

Comment: I have also added extended Picture of the advanced settings in Create File and will move send email out of the loop now.

Comment: I am trying to save the file in the same site there is a library that I have created for the reports to be saved. Can you please help me with the variable you have mentioned that will hold the report information that will be composed in the loop.

Comment: Depending on what you want in your report, you might not even need the loop.  Make sure your `Get Items` action has an Odata query to just retrieve the items modified in the past month, then you can just get the Total number of items from that to put in your report.  If you want to get a list of files, then in your loop you can append a string variable, then after the loop put the value of that variable in your generated report and email.

Comment: Hi @Willman thank you. I'm very new to the SharePoint Online is it possible if you can show me or maybe post a screenshot like example. That will be really great and this thing will be sorted for me then.

Comment: in a simple way , you can pull all the data in windows XL and easily make the report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your exact schema, but for purposes of a prototype, I created a custom List named `ChangeRequests` from which the information will be gathered, and a Document Library named `ChangeReports` to which the generated report will be saved.

Below are the steps and screenshots of the basic Power Automate steps you will need in your Flow to generate your report.  Please note that I did not rigorously test every step since I have no data but what I mocked in my end for prototyping, but hopefully this is more than enough to get you pointed in the right direction.

First, your scheduled trigger looks like it should work just fine.

Next though, your date filters are likely going to always miss the items entered on the last day of the month.  You are currently filtering where `Created is less than or equal to last day of the month` -- but note that SharePoint's datetime value contains the time as well as day, so anything created past 12:01 am will be greater than the date without an appended time.  The way to work around this is to filter where `less than the first day of the next month`.  I also set my start date to be the first day of the previous month -- we don't want to run the report for the current month because the current month is not over yet.  If you run this report on the first or second day of the month, you'd want to grab "last month's" data.

Set `firstDayOfMonth` equal to `startOfMonth(addToTime(utcNow(), -1, 'Month'))`
Set `firstDayOfNextMonth` equal to `addToTime(variables('firstDayOfMonth'), 1, 'Month')`
Then you can get the items from your ChangeRequests list based on those dates:

[image: Screenshot of Flow Steps to Get Items]

Now that you have the items that were created last month, your next goal is to generate a report of that data grouped by the Department of the creator.  I have assumed for my prototype that you would use the built in Author-Department value, but you could easily substitute your own custom metadata field.
To group the data, I recommend you use the technique described by [John Liu](http://johnliu.net/blog/2018/6/do-group-by-in-flow-with-two-simple-elegant-loops) to use two "Apply to Each" loops.
The first loop iterates each item from your results to get a unique list of departments.  Following his pattern, you `Compose` a new entry for your array of Departments by union-ing the departments array variable with a generated entry for the current item's department:  `union(variables('uniqueDepartments'), createArray(items('Apply_to_each_Change_Request_Item')?['Author']?['Department']))`, Then you set the Array to that composed value.  It may seem like it would be more efficient to use a `Condition` block and check whether the current item's Department is already in the Array, and if not, then Append it to the array, but due to how Flow performs comparisons against dynamic values, the Union approach is faster, and actually easier to debug and maintain.

[image: Screenshot of Steps to build Array of Unique Departments]

Following the Same pattern, the Second Loop iterates through your array of unique departments and filters the original results array to just get the Change Request Items for that department, then you can append the appropriate text to your report variables based on that filtered data.  In my case, I am keeping separate variables for the report summary and report body and am appending the counts for each department to the summary, but appending an html table of that department's items to the body.

[image: Screenshot of building report text grouped by Department]

An then finally, once all loops are completed and text composed, you can use `Create file` to save the report in a library, and send `Send an email` to notify the right people about the report.  Note that if you want to create an Office document instead of something text-based like .html or .txt, you have to use a Premium license for Power Automate.  To specify a filename and a subject for the email I use the `formatDateTime` expression to generate the year and month name: `formatDateTime(variables('firstDayOfMonth'), 'mmmm')`.

[image: Screenshot of Creating File and Sending email in Flow]

A big caveat about using `Apply to each` loops in Power Automate -- if you have ever used a `For each` loop in most development languages, there is one big difference here.  In Power Automate, by default the `Apply to each` loop runs many items at once in parallel.  Most languages run the `For each` sequentially, processing each item at a time.  You can change the settings of the `Apply to each` loop to perform that way to, but the default settings are much faster because of the number of processing threads available in the cloud.  But you have to account for that inside your loop.  Notice in a couple of places we append or modify a variable inside our loop, but we don't turn around and try to read from that variable because multiple threads may be modifying it at the same time, and its value may not be what we expect.  We can safely read and use the values from Compose actions because those are encapsulated within each thread.  Other variables we need to wait until the loop is finished to utilize the final result.

Per comment below, here is the expanded early steps to initialize report variables"

[image]

Comment: Hi Willman thank you very much for posting the whole process in detail. I really appreciate your effort and time. 

Thank again,
Noman

Comment: I'm giving it a go and will provide you the feedback thanks

Comment: Hi @willman in the Update Unique Departments like you have done. I can't find any update action in the sharepoint Choose an action. I don't know why it's not coming up for me. As I'm on sharepoint online 2013 as well.

Comment: The action type is `set variable`, but it's good practice to rename your actions to be descriptive of its purpose, similar to how you would name methods and functions if you were writing code.

Comment: Thanks Willman. I am trying to run the flow now and it's giving this error: BadRequest. The variable 'uniqueDepartments' of type 'Array' cannot be initialized or updated with value 'union(variables('uniqueDepartments'), createArray(items('Apply_to_each_Change_Request_Item')?['Impact']?['Summary']))' of type 'String'. The variable 'uniqueDepartments' only supports values of types 'Array'.


But if I change the variable to the String it says it only supports Arrays.

Comment: bro if possible can I see your Initialize reportSummary, Initialize reportBody and initialize uniqueDepartments ?

Comment: That formula should used on the compose action, then the `uniqueDepartments` variable needs to be set to the output from that compose actions.   if you were writing this in code, you would probably do it all in one step and set `uniqueDepartments` directly to the result of the `union` expression, but in Power Automate you cannot reference a variable in the same step that is setting its value,  so the classic method of appending a value in code, such as `x=x+y` would not be legal in a Flow, you would have to compose `x+y` in one step and then set `x=output of compose action` in the next step.

Comment: I added another screenshot at the end of my answer with those Init actions expanded.

Comment: Hi @Willman. Can you please tell what is the value of the length is in Initialize reportSummary and in append departmentCount to reportSummary ?

Comment: Hi @Willman. Sorry to bother you again. But I am still working on this project. Can you please answer my last question?

Comment: I have added the length value as length(body('Get_items')?['value'])   ... It says the right number of reports which is 20. But it also sends the email 20 times. That's weird.

Comment: Those last two actions, the `create file` and `send email` should be after the loop, not inside it.

Comment: yes they are outside the loop.

Comment: Realized send an email is in apply to each. I will take it out now.

Comment: Yes, this thing is sorted now thank you very much. :)

Comment: Thank you Willman. I am able to get the report but I get the scripts as well in the report and I want to know how can I fix this.

For example:
[{"@odata.type":"#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedReference","Id":0,"Value":"NEO"}]

Comment: So, most of the content of the report is coming from the `Create HTML table by uniqueDepartment`, but it is currently creating that table from all field values returned by the query.  On that action, if you click "Advanced Options", then change `Columns` option from "Automatic" to "Custom", then you specify which specific columns go into the report.  Here is more details on how the custom columns option works:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#work-in-designer-view-1

Comment: ok bro. I will try. Thank you for the information and help. You are very kind and helpful. I appreciate all your efforts bro.